# How to wrap text for R shinyWidgets > prettyToggle > label_on (and label_off)

Tags: r

The text for function 'label_on' (shinyWidgets > prettyToggle) is too long and goes outside of the box. How do I wrap the text and stay inside the box?

I found similar problem here but for pickerInput ([How to text wrap choices from a pickerInput, If the length of the choices are long the choices often end up outside the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355878/how-to-text-wrap-choices-from-a-pickerinput-if-the-length-of-the-choices-are-lo)).

I've also added (tags$style(HTML('.pretty .state label { white-space: normal; word-break: keep-all; }')) but it made the icon off set.

```
library(shiny); library(shinydashboard); library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "THE RAFT"),
dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Introduction", tabName = "intro", icon = icon("dashboard")))),
dashboardBody(

  # run this command line to wrap text but as a result icon is off set
  # tags$style(HTML('.pretty .state label { white-space: normal; word-break: keep-all; }')),

  tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "intro", box(title = "Box 1",
                prettyToggle(inputId = "inp001", icon_on = icon("thumbs-up"), icon_off = icon("thumbs-down"),
                             outline = TRUE, plain = TRUE, animation = "rotate",
                             label_off = "Here's some text that takes more than one line on the screen. I want it to wrap, but it just keeps going to the right out of view in its container.",
                             label_on = "Short"
))))))

server <- function(input, output) { }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```